# wordpress change last modified date of the post to post date (scheduled post)

Tags: mysql, wordpress, plugins, modified-date

I have an idea to change the value of `post_modified`, so the value will have the same value with the `post_date`.

But Wordpress has a revision system, so I want to change the `post_modified` on the revision to have a same value with `post_date`.

Here is my query to change it:

```
$query = "UPDATE $wpdb->posts 
          SET 
              post_modified = '$recent->post_date',
              post_modified_gmt = '$recent->post_date_gmt'
          WHERE 
              ID = '$update->ID'";

$wpdb->query($query);


$recent->post_date is the post_date (scheduled time / time where our post will appear in the website)

$recent->post_date_gmt is post_date_gmt
```

`$update->ID` is the revision ID in posts table.

But when I run the query, it doesn't change the value and stops my plugin.

Is there something I missed? Or is it that Wordpress itself doesn't allow us to change the `post_modified`?

Comment: Do you have this `global $wpdb;` line before the `$query` variable?

Comment: yes. i add it in first line of the function

Comment: Can you `echo` your `$query` and paste here?

Comment: UPDATE wp_posts SET post_modified = '2015-01-08 12:15:14', post_modified_gmt = '2015-01-08 12:15:14' WHERE ID = 175

Comment: Query seems good. Do you have any wp cache plugin active?

Comment: i don't use any cache right now

Comment: Hi tidakdijual, vote my following answer if worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the normal wp_update_post function

```
    $args = new stdClass;
    $args->ID = $yourPostIdVal;
    $args->post_modified = $yourDateString;
    $args->post_modified_gmt = $yourGmDateString;
    wp_update_post($args);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same like this problem when I tried to update post_date.Finally I used "`" mark to wrap column names.Do that exactly as follows.

```
$postID = $update->ID;
$datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");   



$wpdb->query( "UPDATE `$wpdb->posts` SET 
                                    `post_date` = '".$datetime."'
                                    WHERE `ID` = '".$postID."'" );
```

Remember, $datetime is a valid date, like 2015-01-04 or 2015-01-04 23:59:59

Hope this would be help.
Thanks